# Symbol identification of this compact surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces

Classify this compact surface:

[image]

where the edges with the same letter identify.

Using the clasification theorem of compact surfaces I get that this is a proyective plane:

The symbol is *abcdabcd* wich, after appliying the symbol transforation rules is equivalent to *aa* , the proyective plane

But if try to classify it using the Euler characteristic I get that χ(X) = $0$ and as I know that this surface is orientable (the 'polygon' does not contain any Mobius strip, anyway I am not really sure about this) then it would be a sphere.

I don´t know what I am doing wrong. Any help is apreciated!

Comment: Your symbol computation is incorrect, try again.

Comment: **abcdab-1c-1b-1** wich after symbol transformatión would be **aabb** the connected sum of two proyective planes, I guess that if there is a Mobius strip in the 'polygon' then both ways will give me the same result. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The connected sum of two projective planes is not the same as the projective plane as written in your question. Now, what is the name of the connected sum of two projective planes and what is its Euler characteristic?

Comment: The connected sum of two proyective planes is homeomorphic to the Klein Bottle, whose charasteristic is $0$. I have been told that the conected sum of a surface a1....an with another surface b1...bn is a1...anb1...b1n, isnt that correct?

Comment: Right. Now, you have resolved the apparent contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much Moishe!